# IN Clause in Dynamic Query

Tags: apex, soql

```
list<string> setknowledgeArticleIds = new list<string>();
setknowledgeArticleIds.addAll(knowledgeArticleIdToHS_Sync.keySet());

knowledgeQuery = 'SELECT Id ,KnowledgeArticleId ,  ' + title + ',' + answer + ' FROM ' + articleType;
        knowledgeQuery += ' WHERE PublishStatus = \'Online\'  AND language = \'en_US\' AND KnowledgeArticleId IN :setknowledgeArticleIds ';
```

> throwing an error : System.QueryException: Variable does not exist:
>   setknowledgeArticleIds

In debug log i can see the query as :

```
SELECT Id ,KnowledgeArticleId ,  title,summary FROM hsinhouse__test_article_type_2__kav WHERE  PublishStatus = 'Online'  AND language = 'en_US' AND KnowledgeArticleId IN :setknowledgeArticleIds
```

Its a strange error . Please let me know if you find solution

Thanks

Comment: where are you running this query?

Comment: its is batch class and running batch class from developer console

Comment: found the issue . !! Sorry guys

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: Scope of the variable was the issue . Query and all were correct . No issues in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a typo* that you typed aphostphe after the setknowledgeArticleIds variable in the last line,
And Please let us know where are you trying to run this code.

If **setknowledgeArticleIds** is a list of ID's you can declare it as `SET<ID> setknowledgeArticleIds` instead of a `List<String> setknowledgeArticleIds`.

```
list<string> setknowledgeArticleIds = new list<string>();
setknowledgeArticleIds.addAll(knowledgeArticleIdToHS_Sync.keySet());

knowledgeQuery = 'SELECT Id ,KnowledgeArticleId ,  ' + title + ',' + answer + ' FROM ' + articleType;
knowledgeQuery += ' WHERE PublishStatus = \'Online\'  AND language = \'en_US\' AND KnowledgeArticleId IN :' + setknowledgeArticleIds;
```